# How do I separate a "println" output from the "BUILD SUCCESSFULL" response from NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, styles

I'm drawing a blank on this one, and I know it has to be a relatively easy fix.

I wrote a program for my java course that generates a random password of ASCII characters 33 - 126 at a user specified length.

Here's an example:
Please enter password length: (input) 5
(output would be something like...) nNd0r .

The program works fine and everything runs smoothly, except for one tiny detail:
When the output is printed, the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" indicator from NetBeans is directly connected to that output.

My real question is: How exactly can I make the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" indicator to be printed *below* my output.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create a Scanner to provide user input.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Prompt the user for their input.
    System.out.print("Please enter password length: ");
    int answer = input.nextInt();

    //Invoke the "randomPassword" method through a loop that was created below.
    System.out.print("Password: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < answer; i++) {
    System.out.print(randomPassword(answer));
    }   
}


    public static char randomPassword(int n) {

    //Create a random number generator.
    int randomNumber = 33 + (int)(Math.random() * ((126 - 33) + 1));

    //Convert random number to random ASCII character between 33 - 126.
    char randomChar = (char)randomNumber;
    return randomChar;
    }

}
```

Comment: All you need is to print a new line after printing the password.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < answer; i++) {
        System.out.print(randomPassword(answer));
    }   
    System.out.println("");

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `System.out.println("");` to the last line of your code.